# sum of the alternating series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+1)/n!$

Tags: calculus

Is there a nice way to see that the series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+1)/n!$$
converges to $0$? I just did the computation numerically.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: compute $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n (n+1)/n!$. To this end, write $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n (n+1)/n!$ as $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \cdot n/n! + \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \cdot 1/n!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{( - 1)}^n}} \frac{{n + 1}}{{n!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}n}}{{n!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{n!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{n!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{n + 1}}}}{{n!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{n!}}}  =  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{n!}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{n!}}}  = 0 \cr} $$

Comment: pretty cool actually)

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $$e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}.$$ If we multiply this by $x$, we get $$xe^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}.$$ Now if we differentiate, we get $$e^{-x}-xe^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)x^{n}}{n!}.$$ We now set $x=1$ to get $$0=e^{-1}-e^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!}.$$